# ajax call with SharePoint REST API to get JSON response

Tags: json, response

I am trying to GET list items from SharePoint 2013 using REST API and ajax call.It is returning by default ATOM+XML. I want the response in JSON format.
I tried the following however still same XML format response:

```
"/_api/lists/getbytitle(ListName)/Items/?$filter=lookupName/LookupNameInSourceListName eq 'col_Name'&                   $select=LinkTitle,Image,lookupName/LookupNameInSourceListName&$expand=lookupName/LookupNameInSourceListName&$orderby=TabOrder asc"

 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The question is opened again. Thanks for your cooperation ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for the answer: i tried no luck.

This one worked for me:

```
$.ajax({
    url: Url,
    method: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {                     
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
    },              
    cache: true,
    error: function (data) {                    ////failure     },              
    success: function (data) {                  ////success     }
});
```

Comment: Mark this as answer, if it is the solution to your problem. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me also! I tried the other three options (odata missing, or nometadata, or minimalmetadata) but only verbose worked... any idea why the other options are broken?  is my sharepoint an older version?  see http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/

Comment: Thank you! I'm on 2019 OnPrem and this worked for me.  What's strange is that most of my api calls returned json by default, but new POSTS returned xml.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your header:

```
"Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

Answer (score 1):

Although already answered, the below worked too :

```
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
```